# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api' (heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku

**tree**

```
├───pzApi
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   db.sqlite3
│   │   manage.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───api
│       │   apps.py
│       │   funcs.py
│       │   urls.py
│       │   views.py
│       │   __init__.py
```

**Procfile**

```
release: python pzApi/manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 pzApi.wsgi:application
```

I'm still trying to deploy this web app and after fixing the wsgi.py not found error by putting it in the same dir as manage.py, now I have another problem where the 'api' folder is not being found, any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you share the code you are using ti import from api ?

Comment: api is a django app, so I can't do that can I?